# content filter hides everything when it is told to filter nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this content filter that filters `<div>`s with the class of container (div.container) by hiding those div that do not contain what is typed inside the input field.

That way it only shows the `<div>`s that contain whatever is typed inside the input field.

Now, it checks and filters on each key up inside the input field so the results seem instant.

Now, my problem is that as a user deletes what is inside the input field, everything is hidden. Whereas when nothing is in the input field, everything should be visible.

It works fine in the separated case [in this js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aegq4/15/)

but not when I applied it to my site as a whole. The filtering works, but everything disappears if nothing is typed in the input.

How can I get it to work so that when nothing is in the input, any div.container that was hidden before becomes visible? So that it works like it should, like a filtre when there is nothing to filtre everything is shown.

[Here is the page](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/270523/help/initializr/index.html#about) where this is happening, to access the filtre that filtres the content below it, click on 'learn more about me' or 'work'.

Comment: Probably because there is a script error on the page. Fix that and let me know if that fixes it.

Comment: @Dom fixed it, I was missing a closing parentheses. But that didn't fix the issue with the filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#filter').keyup(function(){
    if ( $.trim(this.value).length ) 
         $('ul li').hide().filter(':containsLower("'+this.value+'")').show();
    else 
         $('ul li').show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zdznh/